# Rewrite git-svn repository with '--ignore-paths' after clone

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have big svn repository cloned with `git-svn` without any excluding/ignoring directories.

Now, I want to exclude one folder from cloned repo.

It is possible to add `--ignore-paths` to existing git-svn repository? Need to rewrite history to increase free space and accelerate `fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply add it to your config now, the files you ignore in SVN will be frozen in their current states.

You can rewrite history with `git filter-branch` to remove the ignored paths, but the revmap (the table maintained to map SVN revisions to git revisions) won't match up anymore.  I think you can delete that and let it automatically re-generate, as long as you did not disable the SVN revision lines in the git commit comments.

If you later remove the ignore, you'll fail to `git-svn fetch` because the diffs in SVN won't apply to the old files.